# Delay a loop in Java for animation effect

Tags: java, while-loop, slider, sleep, vaadin

I know this is a Duplicate question. But, No answers helped me to solve my problem.
I'm working on a project in [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/). In that I have few layouts ([ref this links to understand my layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335159/vaadin-expand-components-in-grid-layout-in-vaadin)). When I press a button I need to slide the Components in and out. And, I achieved it successfully.

But, My problem is; to make it feel better, I want to slow down the sliding effect. So, It will look like an animation kind of stuff. I'm sliding the Components by changing the setExpandRatio() from 1 to 0.

```
setExpandRatio(component, 1.0f);
```

to

```
setExpandRatio(component, 0f);
```

So that it will slide.

And to slow down the sliding, I tried this.

```
float i = 1.0;
while(i >= 0)
{
  setExpandRatio(component, i);
  i = i - 0.1;
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
      } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

It Just waits for 1 second and slides down the component quickly. I also tried using

```
wait(1000);
```

But, no use. 
Has anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Animator](http://vaadin.com/addon/animator) add-on, it provides nice ways to animate components by using browser's client-side capabilities.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. But, What about ROLL_DOWN_CLOSE_REMOVE & ROLL_RIGHT_CLOSE_REMOVE? Is it not possible to implement them?